# Pandas Carry Result from Calculation to Next Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a dependent calculation to my pandas data frame.  The result of the calculation needs to be added to a value in the next column so the calculation can be computed using the new result.  A scheme for this flow is:

```
Beginning Inventory  |            Beginning Inventory
        |            |      (Ending Inventory from Prev Col)
        |            |                    |
     do math         |                 do math
        |            |                    |
        |            |                    |
Ending Inventory     |             Ending Inventory
```

The "do math" section contains simple addition/subtraction of inventoried items.  How do I calculate the Ending Inventory in such a way that it is carried over to the Beginning Inventory in the next column?

The requested output would look like the following:

```
                       1/2020  |  2/2020  |  3/2020
Beginning Inventory    10000   |  10250   |  10550
Inventory Received       500   |    500   |    300
Inventory Used          -250   |   -200   |   -400
Ending Inventory       10250   |  10550   |  10450
```

I have tried using `df.shift` and `apply` but my understanding of `apply` is incomplete as it returns errors about number of elements.

Any help is appreciated.

```
df["Beginning Inventory"] = df.apply(do math)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show an MRE + expected outcome?

Comment: Added the expected outcome.

Comment: what about the starting point/input? Please post that as well

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some code. Example below is *illustrative*...

If you use dates in long format in your dataframe (df), i.e. dates going down the column, then you can iterate on rows using df.iterrows

```
inv_accumlator=[]
closing_inv_qty=last_closing_inventory
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    closing_inv_qty= closing_inv_qty + row["inventory received"]-row["inventory_used"] 
    inv_accumlator.append(closing_inv_qty)
df['ending_inventory']=inv_accumlator
```